# AQL aggregation functions syntax

Tags: arangodb

What exactly is the syntax for aggregation functions like sum()?

For example, take the following structure:

```
let json = {
    "ages": {
    "age": [
    "20",
    "30",
    "40"
    ]
    }
}
```

and that

```
for age in json.ages.age return age
```

returns

```
 ["20", "30", "40"]
```

All of the following snippets return "[1542] invalid argument type used in call to function 'SUM()'" in Arango 2.0.4:

```
// LR
let ages = (for age in json.ages.age return age)
return sum(ages)

// LR
let ages = (
    for age in json.ages.age  
    return age
)
return sum((for age in json.ages.age return age))

// R
return sum((for age in json.ages.age return age))
```

What is the correct syntax?

The syntax page (http://www.arangodb.org/manuals/current/Aql.html#AqlFunctionsList) does not appear to have any related examples.

The closest thing I could find to a syntax example is this: https://www.arangodb.org/foxx

```
controller.get("/revenue/:year", function (req, res) {
  var query = "RETURN SUM((FOR bill IN billcollection FILTER bill.year == @year     RETURN     bill.amount))"; 
  var stmt = db._createStatement({ "query": query});
  stmt.bind("year",parseInt(req.params("year"),10));
  var c = stmt.execute();
  res.json(c);
});
```

but it seems to have the syntax above that is failing for me.

Is there a more detailed syntax reference anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is correct, however you missed a tiny spot in the docs. ;)

In the docs for SUM() it says:

> SUM(list) : returns the sum of the values in list. This requires the elements in list to be numbers. null values are ignored.

(Docs reference: https://www.arangodb.org/manuals/current/Aql.html#AqlFunctionsList)

Note the **"This requires the elements in list to be numbers"**

So, your JSON-example should have numbers in the list, instead of strings.

```
let json = {
    "ages": {
    "age": [
        20,
        30,
        40
    ]
    }
}

let ages = (for age in json.ages.age return age)
return sum(ages)
```

Copying and running the above snippet into your AQL editor should result in the desired:

```
[
  90
]
```

You can of course also leave your json intact and type-cast the strings into numbers by changing the AQL query accordingly:

```
let json = {
    "ages": {
    "age": [
        "20",
        "30",
        "40"
    ]
    }
}

let ages = (for age in json.ages.age return TO_NUMBER(age))
return sum(ages)
```

Comment: Makes sense.  Used to another, similar language that does that type of conversion automatically, but I didn't even notice that the extraction process is quoting numbers.  Forest for the trees, I suppose.  Thanks much.